# Range Input with space to enter a value too

Tags: javascript, php, slider

thanks for the help right away!

```js
<script>
let rangeValueElement = document.querySelector('#range');
let shippingValueElement = document.querySelector('#shipping');

function calculateShipping(price) {
  const priceShippingRelation = {
    1: 43.51,
    2: 47.05,
    3: 50.61,
    4: 54.15,
    5: 57.71,
    6: 61.25,
    7: 64.81,
8: 68.35,
9: 71.91,
10: 75.45,
11: 79.31,
12: 83.15,
13: 87.01,
14: 90.85,
15: 94.71,
16: 98.55,
17: 102.41,
18: 106.25,
19: 110.11,
20: 113.95,
21: 117.81,
22: 121.65,
23: 125.51,
24: 129.35,
25: 133.21,
26: 137.05,
27: 140.91,
28: 144.75,
29: 148.61,
30: 152.45,
31: 158.31,
32: 160.15,
33: 164.01,
34: 167.85,
35: 171.71,
36: 175.55,
37: 179.41,
38: 183.25,
39: 187.11,
40: 190.95,
  /* ... */
    42: 136,
  /* ... */
  65: 220
  };

  return priceShippingRelation[price];
}

document.querySelector('input#valR').addEventListener('change', showVal);

function showVal() {
  rangeValueElement.innerText = this.value;
  shippingValueElement.innerText = 'Priority Mail (frete): $ ' + calculateShipping(this.value);
}

console.log(calculateShipping(3));

</script>
```

```html
<input id="valR" max="65" min="1" step="1" type="range" value="1">

<span id="range" class="tesxss">1</span>
<div class="tesxsss2"><div id="taxa">Taxa FS Connect: $15.00</div>
<div id="shipping">Priority Mail (frete): 43.51</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I wish that in addition to the slider option, I could insert the number inside a box, so that it could be more direct.
So besides the person doing the "thumb", she could enter a direct number as well.

Another question is: besides normal shipping, there will be two more options. I need to insert two more options, I tried to put more categories, but I could not.
Because the shippings work as follows:
Bronze Shipping: 1-65 lbs
Silver Shipping: 1-10 lbs
Gold Shipping: 1-4 lbs

So if the person entered 3 lbs, there were 3 shipping options, or if they put 55 lbs, only the Bronze Shipping option would appear.

If a button is needed to confirm the values ​​for the shipping options, that's OK!

Thanks for everyone's help, I've tried a lot of topics, but I can not do it the way I need it.

Comment: Java? Are you sure? Looks to be more like JavaScript

Comment: Make `rangeValueElement` an input element and attach a second eventListener to it, so that if one inputs a number there, the range slider updates accordingly.

Comment: Could you explain better? Which code I need?